# Installshield Adding project files

Tags: c#, installshield

I use InstallShield Profesional. In Project Assistant there is an **Application Files** module. With InstallShield LE there is **Add Project Outputs**. With InstallShield LE I add **project1.Primary.output** and it's working. But with InstallShield Profesional, What should I add? I added in BIN/Debug files. it worked with my computer, but when I tested it from another computer it's not working. I checked it program files folder, it installed all files.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I pointed my Application Files to my visual studio projects folder / Bin / Release.  When you build your InstallShield project, it will pull these files from the location you choose and add them to the install process.  The install "setup.exe" should then run fine on another computer and copy the files you specified.